# DataAccess method returning DateTime.MinValue and displaying in UI

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Environment:**
asp.net web forms
3-layer architecture (DAL,Domain, WebForms)
.Net Framework 4.6.1.

How and where would I handle `DateTime.MinValue`? It is `showing 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` in my `gridview` and I'd like it to show a blank.

Comment: you can do at webform layer or DAL layer

Comment: what would i set it to in the DAL?

Comment: set to Empty or null.. better use nullable date time. and insert the database only if it has value. check with DateTime.HasValue()

Comment: Try to use nullable `DateTime? value = null;` in the DAL and it should be passed as null for other layers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [don't display datetime min value in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357000/dont-display-datetime-min-value-in-gridview)