# Show only Date in DataGridView Column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a field as DateTime, I want to display only date( without time ) in my datagridview c#. I get the datetime. example: 22.03.2016 00:00:00
Any help would be appreciated.
I have tried the following:

```
private void bindListToGridView1(List<Item> list)
{
    try
    {
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        ListtoDataTableConverter converter = new ListtoDataTableConverter();
        DataTable dt2 = converter.ToDataTable(listToPresent);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;

        using (dt2)
        {
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "id";
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "id";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "itemName";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Item Name";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "itemName";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "productionDate";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Production Date";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "productionDate";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy'/'MM'/'dd";
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt2;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Here is the method I use to create the `DataTable`:

```
public class ListtoDataTableConverter
{
    public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
        //Get all the properties
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {
            //Setting column names as Property names
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
        }
         foreach (T item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[Props.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {
                //inserting property values to datatable rows
                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
         //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the datetime. 22.03.2016 00:00:00

Comment: in dataTable dt2, what is real type of values in productionDate column? is it a DateTime?

Comment: yes it is public DateTime productionDate { get; set; }

Comment: My comment can be simple, but what about this dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy/MM/dd";
instead of this 
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy'/'MM'/'dd";

Are you using DevExpress?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568483/replacing-a-datetime-minvalue-in-a-datagridview

Comment: I am sorry, i forgot to mention that i tried this.

Comment: Probably the data type of your column in data table is not `DateTime`.

Comment: I am using this class: ListtoDataTableConverter. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1a81c5/list-to-datatable-converter-using-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your column is not of type `DateTime` so when you apply formatting, it doesn't work.

Take a look at the method that creates the data table, you created the columns using `dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);` which it means the `DataType` of column is `string` and formatting will not apply on column. (As I guessed previously)

**Note**

- You don't need to convert a List to a `DataTable` if you want to show it in `DataGridView`, it's enough to set it as `DataSource` of the grid.
- To format a `DateTime` column to show only `Date` part, it's enough to set `DefaultCellStyle.Format` of that column to `yyyy/MM/dd`.
- As a quick fix in your method, you can replace this line of code `dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);` with this line of code: `dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);` which uses data type of property as data type of column.

Comment: I see the problem. but I am not able to do anything with it since i am not a pro programmer. and i am using the class created by another programmer.

Comment: Whilst I don't have any idea about using that method in your application, but as a quick fix you can replace this line of code `dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);` with this line of code: `dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);` which uses data type of property as data type of column.

Comment: Also you don't need to convert a `List` to a `DataTable` if you want to show it in `DataGridView`, it's enough to set it as `DataSource` of the grid.

Comment: Reza Aghaei. I used to use the list as datasource, and i added a new coulum: DataGridViewLinkColumn Deletelink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();, but i faced a problem that whenever i make a refresh, the new added column was added twise.

Comment: This post finds the problem that  you are facing with in the question and describes the reason and offers some solutions (a quick fix and using list) which are applicable. I believe if you have more questions about using a `List<T>` it's better to ask in a separate thread :)

Comment: This way the post will be more useful for future readers :) For more information read [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts)

Comment: this line solved the problem: dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way. Next time, if you add data to DataGridView via clicking the little triangle at the right-top corner of DataGridView;

Edit your **XXXDataSet.Designer** according to:

`this.columnYYY = new global::System.Data.DataColumn("YYY", typeof(**string**), null, global::System.Data.MappingType.Element);`

Change **String** to **DateTime**. Problem solved enjoy. :)