# Blank row in DataGrid if date is equal to 0001-01-01

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a form that the user fills in and as a default a field called `FollowupDate` is set to 0001-01-01. I get an error saying date is in wrong format if I leave the field blank so I had to set it to a default.

When the form is saved it creates a new line in the DataGrid and the followup date shows as 0001-01-01. But if the date is set to this then I would like the row to be blank.

```
foreach (DataGridColumn col in dg.Columns)
{
    if (col.HeaderText == "Follow Up Date")
    {
           // set row to blank                     
    }
}
```

How do I check if the row contains 1/1/0001 and if it does then don't display the date?

[image]

Comment: `DateTime.MinValue` is the solution of your question. A [similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568483/replacing-a-datetime-minvalue-in-a-datagridview) on SO.

Comment: @शेखर but how do I hide the cell if it is equal to DateTime.MinValue?

Answer (score 0):

try this if your date is minimize

```
if(yourColunm == DateTime.MinValue)
{
yourColum = null;
}
```

Comment: In my code I can't set col to DateTime.MinValue I get this error:  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridColumn' and 'System.DateTime'